# Vanilla Javascript and XML - For-loop issue

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am encountering a weird error I can't quite grasp. I think it is an issue with stacked for-loops, but I am not exactly sure. Here is a short explanation of what I do:

*I am reading an XML-File with Vanilla Javascript and display the information in HTML (currently) to see if my code works.*

Each entry gets displayed in a table-row in HTML. "Name" gets it's own "TD" and so does "Keywords". Now I want to display every "Step" as "LI" in an "OL".

It should create one OL for every element "description", but it creates OLs for EVERY element "description" and pushes both OLs into one TD.

*The result is: 2 TDs with both OLs.*

Did I stack the for-loops incorrectly or did I make another mistake?

```js
var getDESC = document.getElementsByTagName("description");
var tblROW = document.createElement("TR");
var tblDATA = document.createElement("TD");
var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
var k;
for (k = 0; k < getDESC.length; k++) {
  var createOL = document.createElement('OL');
  var l;
  for (l = 0; l < getDESC[k].getElementsByTagName("step").length; l++) {
    var createLI = document.createElement("LI");
    var createStep = '';
    createStep = document.createTextNode(getDESC[k].getElementsByTagName("step")[l].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    createLI.appendChild(createStep);
    createOL.appendChild(createLI);
  }
  tblDATA.appendChild(createOL);
  tblROW.appendChild(tblDATA);
}
tbl.appendChild(tblROW);
```

```html
<content>
  <entry>
    <name></name>
    <keywords></keywords>
    <description>
      <step>Text 1</step>
      <step>Text 2</step>
      <step>Text 3</step>
    </description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name></name>
    <keywords></keywords>
    <description>
      <step>Text 1</step>
      <step>Text 2</step>
      <step>Text 3</step>
    </description>
  </entry>
</content>
<table>
<tbody id="tbl"></tbody></table>
```

Expected Output:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Keywords</td>
  <td>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #1"</ol>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Keywords</td>
  <td>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #2"</ol>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My Output:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name for entry #1</td>
  <td>Keywords for entry #1</td>
  <td>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #1"</ol>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #2"</ol>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Name for entry #2"</td>
  <td>Keywords for entry #2"</td>
  <td>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #1"</ol>
   <ol>"Orderered list for entry #2"</ol>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE (09.05.2018):

I like the approach posted below and I'm trying to make it work. It doesn't work correctly yet, but I will post the Javascript first:

I have a function "loadXML()" that does exactly that ("sO(this);" calls the function to create the table etc.):

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      sO(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "content.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I changed the variable of the main-function to include my external XML-File:

```
function sO(xml){
//following line should load the XML-File
var xml = xml.responseXML;
var xmlObject = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xml);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).textContent = "XML";
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre")).textContent = xml;
...
```

The *expected result* would be similar to the table you can see below in the comment.
But my output is: [object XMLDocument].
The "CreateContextualFragment()"-method doesn't read the XML-File correctly I guess, but I am not sure if that really is the mistake.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmWa4.jpg)

Final Update:
I discovered the mistake. I had to add

```
xmlhttp.dataType = "text";
```

to my loadXML() and change

```
var xml = xml.responseXML;
```

to

```
var xml = xml.response;
```

Now it works just fine. Thank your for your help!

Comment: I made you a snippet and added a tbody for the tbl to create a [mcve]

Comment: *It should create one OL for every element "description", but it creates OLs for EVERY element "description"* ??? So, it's creating the correct `<ol>` elements then.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what the expected output should be.

Comment: Hey, I added "expected Output" and "My Output". Hope it clarifies it!

Comment: That's better, but it's still not clear when you say `"Orderered list for entry #1"` - - you want multiple `<ol>`s? or multiple `<li>`s?

Comment: Please show exactly what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Are you saying that there should be a `<tr>` for each `<entry>`?

Comment: Hey, for clarification: I want ONE <ol> for every element <description> and I want ONE <li> for every element <step>. And yes each <entry> should get it's own <tr>.

Comment: Based on the update, where do you get this output? `document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xml)` returns an XML document to search through, so it should have `[object XMLDocument]` type, so maybe your are appending the wrong things to your DOM? Does my example below present the data visually correct?

Comment: I copy-pasted your example into a new projektfolder and it worked just fine. I then wanted to adjust the var xml =" "; to include my XML-File instead of your example-XML. The result just shows [object XMLDocument] . I am not sure where the mistake is to be honest.

Comment: I added a Screenshot at the end which shows my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems stems from `document.getElementsByTagName`. Instead of referencing the document you should be localize your search to any given `entry`.

Here is my take on your problem:

```js
//XML
var xml = "<content>\n<entry>\n  <name>Name1</name>\n  <keywords>key_1 key_3 key_4</keywords>\n  <description>\n\t<step>Text 1</step>\n\t<step>Text 2</step>\n\t<step>Text 3</step>\n  </description>\n</entry>\n<entry>\n  <name>Name2</name>\n  <keywords>key_2</keywords>\n  <description>\n\t<step>Text 1</step>\n\t<step>Text 2</step>\n  </description>\n</entry>\n</content>";
var xmlObject = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xml);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).textContent = "XML";
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre")).textContent = xml;
//Table
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).textContent = "HTML";
var table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>name</th><th>keywords</th><th>description</th></tr>";
table.border = "true";
//treat data
xmlObject.querySelectorAll("entry")
    .forEach(function (entry) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    //name
    row
        .appendChild(document.createElement("td"))
        .textContent = entry.querySelector("name").textContent;
    //keywords
    row
        .appendChild(document.createElement("td"))
        .textContent = entry.querySelector("keywords").textContent;
    //description
    var descriptions = row
        .appendChild(document.createElement("td"))
        .appendChild(document.createElement("ol"));
    entry
        .querySelector("description")
        .querySelectorAll("step")
        .forEach(function (step) {
        descriptions
            .appendChild(document.createElement("li"))
            .textContent = step.textContent;
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: Hey, I really like this approach, but it doesn't work yet. I updated my orginial Post. Thank you for your suggestion already!